# One too many (meaning)

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, expressions

In the movie "*the pursuit of happyness*" by Will Smith in the character of Chris Gardner, the following dialog occurs:

```
A: Jay. 
B: Yes, sir.
A: How many times have you seen Chris?
B: I don't know, one too many, apparently.
```

What does "*one too many*" mean? I wonder if it means "*too many times*".

Comment: One time more than the maximum desired.

Answer (score 2):

The whole answer, "I don't know, one too many, apparently." means that A's question has made B wonder if he may be in trouble for having seen Chris.
  The answer admits that he has seen him, and sarcastically regrets having seen him just enough to have been noticed.
 So, "too many times" is correct, but doesn't catch the full flavor of the answer.